# C++ pass pointer twice?

Tags: c++, pointers

I cannot figure out this: I have to pass a pointer to a function, and then somewhere in this function I need to pass the pointer again to a second function.

Basically something like this:

```
int main()
{
  int x = 1;
  foo(&x);
}


void foo(int *p)
{
  foo2(p);
}

void foo2(int *p)
{
   *p = 2;
}
```

I tried multiple ways but I cannot get it right. How is this done?

Comment: where is the declaration?

Comment: What isn't going right?

Comment: If you compile it with pre-c99 C, and the pointers are to high addresses, then it might be a runtime error. Otherwise (c99 / C++) it will not compile.

Comment: In future, please actually include any errors/warnings you receive from the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you need to declare functions before you use them.

```
// Declare the functions to be defined later.
// this lets us use them in main before we write the
// definitions.
void foo(int *);
void foo2(int *);

int main()
{
  int x = 1;
  foo(&x);
}


void foo(int *p)
{
  foo2(p);
}

void foo2(int *p)
{
    *p = 2;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed the problem was in the declaration. I wasn't declaring the second int as a pointer. I wasn't sure the way I wrote it on the question was right also so thanks.